# Can I use "That would be nicer if..." in this context?

Tags: word-usage

On a tweet I wrote, I said "It would be nicer if there was more RAM". I was telling this because somebody complained about the lack of RAM, and by "nicer" I meant that it would be better/more pleasant...
Am I right to use "nicer" in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. *[nicer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nice?q=nice)* is okay as you want to mean *better, more pleasant* with that speed.

However, I'd prefer telling it this way...

> It would be nicer if *it had more RAM.*

Comment: I like your sentence too, although I think the OP's is okay.  Personally, if I said it like the OP, I'd go for "if there were" rather than "if there was", although that's not a requirement.

Comment: @snailplane initially I thought of *were* but then dropped it is RAM comes as a chip and considering it plural wouldn't have been that smooth-looking. Though I understand *if . . . .were* structure

Comment: *Were* here is an irrealis form which is not specifically plural.  It works fine with singular nouns.